# Choice of complementary function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm currently working on solving some DE's and came across this one.

$y''-y=xe^{2x}$

And the characteristic polynomial has a double root at 1. Now finding the complementary function would normally (at least for me) be using $y=Ae^x+Bxe^x$

However, in the solutions, they use $y=A\cosh x + B\sinh x$.

What was their motivation for such a choice? Should using my original choice $y=Ae^x+Bxe^x$ still work?

Comment: Do you have an initial condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The characteristic polynomial **does not** have a double root.

Choosing $e^x$ and $e^{-s}$ or $\sinh x$ and $\cosh x$ are equivalent. Each of $\sin h x$ and $\cosh x$ is a linear combination of $e^x$ and $e^{-x}$, and vice-versa.

Comment: Silly me! Apparently $x^2=1$ has double roots now.

Comment: Well, it does have *two* roots!